# how can adding Key float values from NSDictionary to NSarray?

Tags: iphone, ios, json

My brain is fried! I can't think. 
 i am new to iphone programming

am doing json parsing ....in that am storeing data from json to nsdictionary but .......
I want to add all nsdictionary float values from the dictionary to the array. This is what I am doing right now.As code below:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
  [connection release];

   NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
   self.responseData = nil;

   dict = [responseString JSONValue];

            NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
           for (NSString *key in [dict allKeys])
          {

               array = [dict objectForKey:key];
           // array return float values but
        [array addObject:array ];  // geting carsh dude to array return float values like 120.01  

}
```

Please guide me i am not getting a part where i am doing a mistake.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your app is crashing because you are adding data to `NSArray` , this is static array, you can not add value at run time, so just Make `NSMutableArray` and add your data in `NSMutableArray`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is broken in a couple of ways.

This line assigns the array pointer to the object in the dictionary:

```
array = [dict objectForKey:key];
```

Then you are trying to add the array to itself, which does not make sense. But worse, since `array` does no longer point to your `NSMutableArray` you cannot even call that method.

```
[array addObject:array ];
```

You probably wanted to do something like this:

```
for (NSString *key in [dict allKeys])
{  
     id value = [dict objectForKey:key];              
     [array addObject:value];     
}
```

Comment: thanks for the rapid response. but how can do instand off dzz ....  array = [dict obje*emphasized text*ctForKey:key];..after dz line if i print array values am geting all values from nsdictionary ....am confuse how to add objectkey to return array ...please note that array return float values????

Comment: Perhaps your dictionary for the given key, actually contains an array of values ? It is difficult to answer more specific without knowing the context. I don't think the fact that it is float values are important here, since if they are in the dictionary, then they should already be `NSValue` instances; but just for completeness, you can only add objects to an array, not simple types such as `float`.

Comment: Also, try using the debugger and inspecting the different values. If value is indeed a simple type, try wrapping with `NSValue`.